# Likes on home page are no longer showing

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My homepage at http://www.kccurling.com no longer shows the likes.  Though the other pages I set the ability to like is uneffected and does show their respective likes.

When I click the like button.  rather than showing my facebook avatar I get a red "error".  Clicking on the "red error", I get the following message

"There was an error liking the page. If you are the page owner, please try running your page through the linter on the Facebook devsite (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/) and fixing any errors."

I then go the link provided. Type in the url and can see the number of likes for that page. by clicking the link at the bottom of the page.   I click on debug. but that appears to do nothing.   I am not savey enough to understand or see why the likes are still no longer showing on this page only.

This happen about the time I set up a facebook fan page but I am not sure if the two are linked.

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Working fine for me.. "229 people like this. Be the first of your friends."

Answer (score 0):

Its most likely a temporary error.

Its worth making sure your Open Graph tags are present and working as per the linter.

You may need to wait an hour before linting again.

If its still borked in a couple of hours then there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen today a strange behaviour on my site too. The like button doesn't seem to work any longer. Then I've tried to create again a new like button on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/. And this points in two directions. First I get a new `app_id` (but I don't know why). And second thing was, that I've had to verify my account by SMS or credit card. After that, all was fine...